# Solr Query: How to use date boost inside a query for the Standard Query Parser?

Tags: search, solr

So far I have seen examples with date boost used mainly in queries for Dismax Query Parser. 
So, for example, if I have `q=title:superman subject:superman`, how would I add `"{!boost b=recip(ms(NOW,manufacturedate_dt),3.16e-11,1,1)}"` to it?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
q={!boost b="recip(ms(NOW,manufacturedate_dt),3.16e-11,1,1)"}(title:superman subject:superman)
```

If you want to multiply that boost by 100, then you can do:

```
q={!boost b="product(100,recip(ms(NOW,manufacturedate_dt),3.16e-11,1,1))"}(title:superman subject:superman)
```

Refer to [Solr function query wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) for more functions and examples.

Comment: This is just the syntax. Why and how it works is very well explained in the wiki here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents

Comment: But on SO answers should be self contained. Can you explain it for the asker?

Comment: Is it possible to boost the date boost?

Comment: Such as: q={!boost b="recip(ms(NOW,manufacturedate_dt),3.16e-11,1,1)^100"}(title:superman subject:superman) ?